# Linker error after migrating from VS2008 to VS2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012

We have migrated from VS2008 to VS2012.
All the C# projects have been migrated successfully.

But we have one VC++ project which is throwing Linker error on .DEF file on compilation.It throws the following error

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol Test

Are there any known issues documented for this? Any work arounds?

Comment: You might need to recompile some of your libraries in VS2012.

Answer (score 0):

It implies that you have defined a function named Def in the .DEF file but have not written the same function in your header file. Probably you have written the function in your code file but not declared the same in header file.

If you have already declared it in header file, probably you have not declared it as an extern function.

If this does not resolve your question, please provide code your header and source file along with def file

Comment: It is there in the header file.It was working in Vs2008 and not in Vs2012,so it should be some settings issue rather than a code issue

Comment: Try following instructions on this url http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ys435b3s.aspx and also instructions on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ys435b3s.aspx